# issue when changing record limit in php dynamic pagination

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and was trying to created dynamic pagination to show record form MySQL.
The issue I'm facing is when I change number of record to be show by using SELECT tag it only works once after that it goes back to default value that i have set -> `$limit = isset($_POST['records-count'])?$_POST['records-count']:"10";` which is 10.

**PHP**

```
    include('../config/DbFunction.php');
    $obj = new DbFunction();
    
    $limit = isset($_POST['records-count'])?$_POST['records-count']:"10";
    $page = isset($_GET['page'])? $_GET['page']:"1";
    $start_data = ($page-1)*$limit;
    $rs = $obj->view_course($limit,$start_data);
    //print_r($limit); // to check limit value
    $course_row = mysqli_fetch_row($obj->view_course1());
    $total_records = $course_row[0];
    $total_page = ceil($total_records/$limit);
    $next = $page + 1 > $total_page? $total_page : $page +1;
    $prev = $page - 1 == 0? 1 : $page - 1;
    ?>
```

**Form**

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    Records: <select name="records-count" id="records_count"> 
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Limit</option>
        <?php foreach([20,50,100,200] as $limit): ?>
        <option <?php if( isset($_POST["records_count"]) && $_POST["records_count"] == $limit) echo "selected" ?> value="<?= $limit; ?>"><?= $limit; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Pagination**

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-default">
        <li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href="view-course.php?page=<?= $prev; ?>">Previous</a></li>
        <?php     
            for ($i=1; $i<=$total_page; $i++) { 
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='view-course.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
            } 
        ?>
        <li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href="view-course.php?page=<?= $next; ?>">Next</a></li>       
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to store and retrieve it from session. Session will allow to store variable in server

you need to start the session before send anything to client.

```php
session_start();
```

```
if(isset($_POST['records-count']))
    $_SESSION["records-count"] = $_POST['records-count'];
```

last thing to note is:

- session variable will be updated in next requests.

Comment: exactly I don't want the variable to b update on next request until I select the amount of record i want to view

Answer (score 0):

After so many try I got the solution by using GET method

So i Change

```
 $limit = isset($_POST['records-count'])?$_POST['records-count']:"10";

<div class="pagination">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-default">
        <li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href="view-course.php?page=<?= $prev; ?>">Previous</a></li>
        <?php     
            for ($i=1; $i<=$total_page; $i++) { 
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='view-course.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
            } 
        ?>
        <li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href="view-course.php?page=<?= $next; ?>">Next</a></li>       
    </ul>
</div>
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['records-count'])) {
        $limit = $_POST['records-count'];
    } else {
        $limit = empty($_GET['records'])? "2":$_GET['records'];
    }

<div class="pagination">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-default">
        <li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href="view-course.php?page=<?= $prev; ?>&records=<?= $limit; ?>">Previous</a></li>
        <?php     
            for ($i=1; $i<=$total_page; $i++) { 
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='view-course.php?page=".$i."& records=".$limit."'>".$i."</a></li>";
            }   
        ?>
        <li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href="view-course.php?page=<?= $next; ?>&records=<?= $limit; ?>">Next</a></li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

If anyone know more efficient or better way then this plz let me know.